# electron loadURL re-renders the same page

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to receive the name of a new file from the front-end using ipcRenderer, sending it to electron and using ipcMain to listen to this event and load a new view for the window. However, the loadURL re-renders the same view. I've checked and made sure that the correct name is sent back back and that the path to the file is correct.

Here is a code snippet of the two method calls:

---

```
let win

const createWindow = () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.ejs'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

ipcMain.on('redirectToView', (event, metadata) => {
  const pathToView = `${__dirname}/src/views/${metadata.viewName}.ejs`;
  const URL = url.format({
    pathname: pathToView,
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  })
  win.loadURL(URL);
})
```